# How can I store symbols?

Tags: php, mysql, character-encoding, symbols

I want to store symbols like █ ▄ in my mysql db and show them with php.
I tried to use ord and chr but it shows this symbol after: â

How can I do that?

Kind regards, Damon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: are you using image as a symbol ?

Comment: If UTF-8 was the issue, I take it you wouldn't mind if I closed this as a duplicate of the other one - so that folks would quickly see where the answer is?

Comment: I assume you are off writing great code somewhere. I am closing it as a duplicate. If this indeed wasn't the issue, please leave a comment and I will reopen. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 0):

I think You cannot store logo directly to the database.

you have to get the link or url of the logo into a variable and then store this into database.